# share google spread sheet to everyone in python

Tags: python, google-sheets, oauth, gspread

I've a sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]],
index=["row 1", "row 2"],
columns=["col 1", "col 2"],
)
```

I need to write this dataframe to google spread sheet. For that I've created a google service account

```
FOLDER_PATH = "/home/"
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, 'auth.json')
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
```

My `Google.py`

```
import pickle
import os
import datetime
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
   print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
   CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
   API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
   API_VERSION = api_version
   SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
   print(SCOPES)

   cred = None

   pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
   # print(pickle_file)

   if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
      with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
          cred = pickle.load(token)

   if not cred or not cred.valid:
       if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
        cred.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        cred = flow.run_local_server()

    with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(cred, token)

try:
    service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
    print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
    return service
except Exception as e:
    print('Unable to connect.')
    print(e)
    return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
  dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
  return dt
```

My `gsheet.py`

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from Google import Create_Service
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account

FOLDER_PATH = "/home/"
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, 'auth.json')
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
sheets_file1 = service.spreadsheets().create(body={}).execute()
```

`sheets_file1` contains the sheet url, How can I give access of the url to everyone since it is restricted only to my service account?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to use the Drive API to do this.*

#### More Information:

To change the permissions of a file, you need to create a Permissions resource on the file using the [Drive API method `permissions: create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create).

For this you will need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope - make sure that the Drive API is enabled for your project, redownload your  credentials, delete your loacal token file and reauthenticate the application.

```py
FOLDER_PATH = "/home/"
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, 'auth.json')
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
DRIVE_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SHEETS_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

drive_service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, 'drive', 'v3', DRIVE_SCOPES)
sheets_service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, 'sheets', 'v4', SHEETS_SCOPES)

sheets_file1 = sheets_service.spreadsheets().create(body={}).execute()

resource = {
    "role": "writer",
    "type": "anyone"
}
    
permission = drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=sheets_file1["id"],body=resource).execute()
```

Make sure to change the `role` parameter to fit your requirement.

#### Reference:

[Permissions: create | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)